# Flexible flat cable formerly connected to vibration motor got torn off, does anyone know how I could go about fixing this?

Tags: soldering, vibration, ffc

Here are some images to show you what I'm dealing with:

[image: Above and below the cable]

From what I can see, the cable used to be glued onto the motor, with solder on the top. I'm not very experienced with such repairs, to attempt to glue it back together.  Do I rely on reapplying solder below the cable to get them to stick? Does the vibration motor connect with the cable via the brown portion? The motor has no cables sticking out, instead, a brown patch is seen at the top.

EDIT: I'll provide more pictures, sorry, this is my first post here:

[image: View without my hand blocking]

[image: Another look]

Comment: We can’t see much, apart from your manicured fingernails. we need more pictures.

Comment: Thanks! Never had my nails manicured but I guess that is a compliment, I attached more pictures with my hand out of the way so more of the part could be seen

Comment: Does the flex PCB flex during operation? If not, I would just solder regular cables to fix any broken connection.

Comment: It does not have any regular cables, how would I go about soldering regular cables on this connection? It seems as though they were formerly glued together

Answer (score 0):

Basically the solder job looks very questionable. The whole joint has come loose which wouldn't be possible if it was actually soldered correctly. This means that it was applied to some surface where the solder doesn't wet for whatever reason - maybe it isn't metal, maybe it's enamelled or covered with lacquer etc. Or maybe it's just a classic cold joint.

If there's meant to be an electrical connection there, then the only option is soldering. Or in case these only serve as mechanical strain relief and the soldering was merely some sort of "poor man's glue", then you could replace them with actual glue.

But if they have to be soldered, there must be a proper metal surface on both sides where you can actually solder something. If so, then you should re-do these joints. Remove them with a solder wick copper braid, clean up, add flux, solder anew.

Now the real question is if any of the metal traces inside the FFC are damaged - repairing those in a professional way is more or less impossible. I'd replace the whole cable in that case.